# Webpack Dev-Server And React Server Side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I'm experimenting with isomorphic React applications, and I'm having issues when doing hot-loading on webpack dev server. I get this error:

> warning.js:44 Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container
>   but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using
>   server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what
>   the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate
>   which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server
>   rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is
>   different on the client or server

I do know what the meaning of this, but I have no idea how to fix it.
Also, take note that this **ONLY** occurs when I change my code which results in hot reload of the dev server, on production or on initial load of the dev server, no warnings are shown.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some expirementing I've realized the problem occured only when editing [React Stateless Functions](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions), as mentioned [here](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md#the-following-modules-couldnt-be-hot-updated-they-would-need-a-full-reload).
Changing the component to its' ES6 class form, solved the problem. Note that `react-hot-loader v3.x` (which is currently alpha), doesn't have that problem.